# Add items to existing SharePoint lists by coding

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-designer

I want to add items to a still existing SharePoint list by self-coding.

So I searched the internet and found a lot of information how to create lists, add items and so on..

```
SPWeb mySite = SPContext.Current.Web;
SPListItemCollection listItems = mySite.Lists[TextBox1.Text].Items;
SPListItem item = listItems.Add();
```

The coding seems easy, but where i have to put the code?
I programmed Web Parts and deployed these to my web application.
This was no problem, but here i am missing an approach.

I am using VisualStudion 2008 and SharePoint WSS 3.0

Thank you for any help.

Comment: The answer depends on what you are trying to accomplish.  You may be moving data from another system or adding some cross-site automation from within SharePoint.  Tell us what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the purpose - why are you doing this?

- Do you have one specific list where you (as the owner/administrator) need to create items and this has to be done only once? If yes, then you can do it [with Powershell, as in this Karine Bosch's post](http://www.u2u.info/Blogs/karine/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=11).
- If you need your users to be able to add items to list using program code, then web parts is the way to go. Then you will want to build a nice user interface for that webpart. And then you can deploy your webpart to your server, create a page in your site and add the webpart to the page.
- If you need to create the new list item as soon as something else happens (for instance, a list item is created in some other list, then think of [event handlers](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brianwilson/archive/2007/03/05/part-1-event-handlers-everything-you-need-to-know-about-microsoft-office-sharepoint-portal-server-moss-event-handlers.aspx).

Answer (score 4):

```
SPWeb app = SPContext.Current.Web;
SPList ListName = app.Lists["YourListName"];
SPListItem ListItem = ListName.Items.Add();
ListItem["field1Name"] = value;
ListItem["field2Name"] = value;
ListItem.Update();
```

Answer (score -1):

you are doing some modification on site ...so after that we need to update the site ..Use ListItem.update();

Comment: I'll do mysite.update(),
but on which file i have to include the code?
is there an existing file?